# How to include stylesheet in custom admin using parent_slug

Tags: themes, customization, admin, slug, options

Using this code from codex:

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {
if( 'edit.php' != $hook )
    return;
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugins_url('/myscript.js', __FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

this will add a custom stylesheet into wp-admin on the edit page, how can we change this so that we can use a slug from a custom admin options page which has submenus, is there a way we can use the parent menu item slug?

[b]EDIT[/b]:

This is how i have adapted the above code:

```
function auctionwp_custom_admin_style($hook) {
if( 'edit.php' != $hook )
    return;
wp_enqueue_style( 'my_custom_script',  get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) .  '/css/custom_style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'auctionwp_custom_admin_style' );
```

what im now trying to do is change the if statement to use parent menu slug rather than edit.php

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse menu structure with page/URL structure. Each one of your pages may have a different hook.

Do this:

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    echo $hook;
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

Load your pages and write down the hook names.

There may be other ways to do this too, like the `admin-print-scripts-$hook_suffix` hooks. Look in `wp-admin/admin-header.php` to see what I mean, about line 68.

Comment: Thanks for that, using your example it has given me the way foreward.